# Android Widget Popup

Tags: android, android-widget, popupwindow, android-alertdialog

I would like to make a popup window with a textview from my widget (AppWidgetProvider), I want 2 buttons in the bottom "Update" and "Close".
I tried using a AlertDialog but it crashes the widget.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Sample text")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           CallUpdate(context);
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            builder.show();
```

I want to be able to use Spanned text.

Thanks.

Comment: How does it crash?  I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you have there but of course we can't run it ourselves...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an App Widget can support the following layout classes:

```
FrameLayout
LinearLayout
RelativeLayout
```

And the following widget classes:

```
AnalogClock
Button
Chronometer
ImageButton
ImageView
ProgressBar
TextView
ViewFlipper
ListView
GridView
StackView
AdapterViewFlipper
```

so you can not show `AlertDialog` from `AppWidgetProvider`. You can start an actvity on button click which look like a alertDialog.

FOR LAUNCHING an activity on Home Screen Widget click you can see these posts:

[Launching activity from widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937236/launching-activity-from-widget)

[How to launch activity from android home screen widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706464/how-to-launch-activity-from-android-home-screen-widget)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot display an `AlertDialog` from an `AppWidgetProvider`. You will need to create an `Activity` and use that instead, via `startActivity()`. You can [theme the activity to look like a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979631/115145) if you so choose.